# Troubleshooting my work for a related rates question

Tags: calculus, related-rates

[image]

This is the cross section of a truck tank, **which is three metres long**. All angles are in radians.

In a previous part to this question, we were asked to determine an expression for the volume of the left hand side of the tank.

This is what we obtained:

$$V=\begin{cases}
\frac{3}{4}(2\beta - \sin2\beta), &0\le \beta \le \frac{\pi}{2}\\
\frac{3}{4}(2\beta + \sin2\beta), & \frac{\pi}{2} < \beta \le \frac{5\pi}{6}
\end{cases}$$

Now, the question is, if the left part of the tank is being filled at a constant rate at $0.001m^3/s$, how much longer will it take to fill the left hand side of the tank.

Now, the given solution plugs in the value of beta when the tank is full (i.e. $5\pi/6$ radians) as follows:

[image]

However, I adopted a different approach. I calculated the area of the entire circle ($\pi$) and from this subtracted the minor segment EC (not actually shown in the diagram above). All of this gave me the following as the volume of the left hand side of the tank:

$$3\cdot\frac{\pi - \frac{\pi}{6} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}4}2$$

which is approximately equal to $4.58m^3$. This is not the same answer as the method above. Can anyone see where I am going wrong? I am sure it must be something very silly indeed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula obtained in the the question's previous part is wrong: $V$ actually turns out to have the same expression for both the given cases of $\beta.$ This wrong formula also fails a sanity check: [according to it](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dhkvpsorzi), $V$ undergoes a sharp change as $\beta$ increases past $\frac{\pi}2.$

Let G be the intersection of AO produced and the water level. For $\beta\in\left(\frac{\pi}2,\frac{5\pi}6\right],$ the water’s cross-sectional area is $$\text{area of sector  } OAF+\text{area of } OFG\\=\frac12\left(1^2\right)\beta+\frac12(1)(OG)\sin(\pi-\beta)\\=\frac12\beta+\frac12\cos(\pi-\beta)\sin(\pi-\beta)\\=\frac14\left(2\beta+2(-\cos\beta)\sin\beta\right)\\=\frac14\left(2\beta-\sin2\beta\right).$$

Thus, the full left-side volume (given by $\beta=\frac{5\pi}6$ and cylinder length $3\mathrm{m}$) is $4.58\mathrm{m}^3,$ which is consistent with the value obtained using your alternative approach.

Comment: I understand parts of what you are saying but am confused about others. When you say the formula obtained is wrong, I think the way they explained that was: if we consider sector OAF as it is drawn currently in the original diagram, then the area of the water is the sector OAF MINUS the unshaded triangle. If we go past the 90 degrees, then we must ADD the triangle. The max value come when we the line from B reaches point E thus showing that we must ADD triangle ODE. Can you see what they are doing wrong?

Comment: Also, I don't quite understand where you derive your formula for V from - please could you clarify?

Comment: Thanks! I see what you mean now. But what about their explanation [explained in my first comment above]?

Comment: The $\frac{1}{4}\sin{2\beta}$ term came from $\frac{1}{2}\cos{\beta}\sin{\beta}$, which is the triangle area, where $\cos{\beta}$ is the length of the base (or height depending on your point of view). Note that this length becomes negative for $\beta>\pi/2$, making the area negative. This already gives you the sign change you want. You formula assumes that the area is always positive and changing the sign to match, but that is incorrect unless you also put in absolute value signs. around the area term.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis The OP's book divided the setup into two cases (**such that OG is positive in both cases**), but got the 2nd case wrong, so I was deriving *merely case 2* —which is why my derivation begins as “For $\beta\in\left(\frac{\pi}2,\frac{5\pi}6\right]$”. Your suggestion OTOH is to treat the setup a a single case, which is valid, but not our goal (to troubleshoot the given working, and to do it accessibly for the OP).  Read my derivation carefully to realise that all three approaches (the OP’s own attempt, yours, and mine) give the same final expression.

Comment: @Rushi “If we go past the $90$ degrees, then we must add the triangle. The max value comes when the line from $B$ reaches point $E$ showing that we must add triangle ODE.”  1. There's a typo: they mean point $O$ instead of point $B.$  2. Their explanation is otherwise correct—but incomplete, since deriving $V$ on $(\frac{\pi}2,\frac{5\pi}6)$ has not actually been described. Examine their actual derivation to see where they went wrong: most likely some algebraic error while applying trigo identities. 3. Their verbal explanation unnecessarily treats $\beta=\frac{5\pi}6$ as a separate case.