# Height of arbitrary point on circle segment

Tags: geometry, circles

Given a circle segment with radius $r$ and chord length $d$:

How can I compute the height $h$ over the chord of a circle point depending on angle $\alpha$?

NOTE: For the special case where $\alpha = \theta/2$, with $\theta$ being the central angle, the height $h$ equals the sagitta, but I am looking for a solution for generalised $\alpha$.

[image: Arc segment]

Comment: Are you assuming, as suggested in diagram, that the two radii labelled $r$ are inclined from the horizontal through the circle center at the same angle, measured from the given radius to the appropriate side of the diameter through the circle center?

Comment: @coffemath Isn't that always true?

Comment: It wouldn't be true if the diagram were rotated a bit around the circle center. Which is why I asked.

Comment: @coffemath, ah okay, the line labeled $d$ isn't always horizontal. I thought you meant the angle between $d$ and $r_1$ resp. $d$ and $r_2$, which are always the same.

Comment: @coffemath, I added a note to the query, clarifying that for the special case of $\alpha$ being half the central angle, the solution is the sagitta.

Comment: Similar to the question that I just answered: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4227356/21813

Answer (score 0):

From the center, draw the perpendicular to the cord. Let's call $M$ the intersection with the cord, and $T$, the intersection with the circle at the top. Let $O$ be the center of the circle, $AB$ the cord, and $P$ the point where you want to measure the distance to $AB$. Then $OA=OP=r$. $$OM=r\cos\frac\theta2$$
Let $P'$ be the foot of the perpendicular on $OT$ from point $P$. Then $$OP'=r\cos\left(\frac\theta 2-\alpha\right)$$
and $$h=OP'-OM=r\left[\cos\left(\frac\theta 2-\alpha\right)-\cos\frac\theta2\right]$$

Answer (score 0):

Half of the subtended angle $\theta$ satisfies $$\sin \frac{\theta}{2} = \frac{d}{2r},$$ and the altitude of the triangle is $y = \sqrt{r^2 - (d/2)^2}$. For an angle $\alpha \in [0, \theta]$, the angular deviation from the maximum height $h$ is $|\frac{\theta}{2} - \alpha|$, thus $$\cos \left|\frac{\theta}{2} - \alpha \right| = \frac{h + y}{r}.$$  Solving for $h$ yields
$$h = r \cos \left|\arcsin \frac{d}{2r} - \alpha \right| - \sqrt{r^2 - (d/2)^2}.$$